# Asyncio and aiohttp put requests

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to develop some code that will hit an api with a put. I want to hit the api probably a few thousand times, however I'm not sure how to handle the errors in the following example. If I wanted to stop processing, how is this done? Is there any control over each put request?

````
    import aiohttp
    import asyncio
    import time

   start_time = time.time()

   async def send_payload(session, url):
        payload = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}'        
        token = {'apikey':'abcd'}

       async with session.put(url, data=payload, headers=token) as resp:
            result = resp.status, await resp.text()            
       return result

   async def main():
        session_timeout = 60
        timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=3)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)) as session:
            global count
            global errcount
            count = 0
            errcount = 0
            tasks = []
            for number in range(1, 151):
                url="https://myapi.com/test"
                # This is where it executes to the api???
                tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(send_payload(session, url)))          
                results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           # Is this after execution and just process the results, or is this as it  is executed?
           for result in results:
                count = count + 1
                if result[0] != 200:
                    print(result[0], "Found an issue")
                    errcount = errcount + 1               
                else:
                    print(count, result[0], result[1],  "\n\n")

   asyncio.run(main())
    print("processed",count,"records errors", errcount,"which took %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))```
````

Answer (score 0):

asyncio.gather raises the first exception encountered by any of the tasks and leave the other tasks running in the background.

If you want each task to run “independently”, handle exception in send_payload().  Alternatively, pass return_exceptions=True to asyncio.gather() so that it waits for all tasks to complete (or err).